# Laravel File Upload with new name

Tags: php, laravel, file, file-upload

I have the following code:

```
$randomNameCV = substr(md5(uniqid(rand())), 0, 10).date('YmdHi').".pdf";

$storeCV =  $request->cv->store('storage/cvs','public');
```

Which allows me to upload files, however I can't upload when I specify the name of the file using these methods:

```
$storeCV = $request->cv->storeAs(
    'storage/cvs', $randomNameCV
);

$storeCV = Storage::putFileAs(
    'storage/cvs', $request->file('cv'), $randomNameCV, 'public'
);
```

[Documenation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem#file-uploads)

Answer (score 0):

Like this - remember about extesion:

```
Storage::putFileAs('photos', new File('/path/to/photo'), 'photo.jpg');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here "avatar" is the field name of the form -

```
// name of the file
$randomNameCV = substr(md5(uniqid(rand())), 0, 10).date('YmdHi').".pdf";

// path and file name -- here public is folder name and randomNamecv is file

$path = 'public/'.$randomNameCV;
$request->file('avatar')->store($path);
```